# Slow draining/gurgling kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing

I unscrewed and cleaned both p-traps, but both drains still back up. I then tried pouring in hot water, plunging, and a 25ft auger. Didn't reach any blockage. Could this be caused by incorrect piping, or a failed Air Admittance Valve?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STKrB.jpg
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If this is a recent problem it's not caused by incorrect plumbing. AAVs can malfunction and are fairly simple to replace - try it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things it could be that would be better diagnosed by inspecting the plumbing.  But probably the most common cause is a partial blockage from accumulated food waste, which can be much farther away from the kitchen sink than homeowner tools can deal with.  If water is still flowing at all, it will be harder to diagnose.

But generally, waste sticks to the pipe walls, and tends to build up plugs especially where there is a bend or joint, or a smaller pipe joins a larger pipe.  An auger can ream it out (it typically won't get 100% clean, but a big improvement, and it can remove plugs of waste).  However, if the problem is a long distance from the sink and there are a number of bends and joints along the way, it is likely to require a professional-grade powered auger to handle the job.

If you can locate the blockage, you may be able to cut out a section of pipe close to it to better access it, then reconnect the pipe ends with a rubber coupler or cleanout coupler so you can access it again in the future when the same spot plugs up again.

If the drain is fully plugged or almost fully plugged, you may be able to locate the blockage by feeling the weight of the pipe and sometimes by tapping on it.  A pipe full of water or buildup will have more of a dull thud.

Another diagnostic tool is to fill sinks around the house (including upstairs if there is one), and then simultaneously open their stoppers with the faucet still running to give the drain pipes some water to deal with.  Anything that drains freely is feeding the house discharge line past the blockage.  Anything that is on the same side of the blockage as the kitchen is likely to cause loud bubbling noises in other blocked sinks, and may cause the water to temporarily back up in the sinks farthest from the blockage.  You can then follow the drain pipes in the basement to get an idea of where the blockage is likely to be.

Once you're at the point where it drains slowly and gurgles (I assume you mean a "blub blub" sound of big air bubbles), flushing with hot water won't be very effective.  That's better as a preventative measure to reduce build-up.  BTW, don't use boiling hot water, as that will soften solidified grease and redistribute it to parts of the pipe farther down.  Use hot water from the tap and mix in some detergent.

Fill a number of sinks that feed the same drain pipe and add a squirt of detergent to each.  Then with the faucets still running, remove the plugs from all of them at the same time.  That will fill the drain pipe with hot soapy water under a little gravity pressure, which will be a little more effective than just running the tap.  Repeating once all the water has drained will give it another shot.  Doing this maybe once a week will help to slow the speed of buildup.

My recommendation would be to not use chemical drain cleaners.  If there is only a partial blockage and water still drains, they would be a total waste.  The chemicals need to be in contact with the waste for a long time to do anything.  If there is a complete blockage and the product indicates it's safe for the pipes to leave it in place for a long time (hours), it might help.  Depending on what kind of waste is causing the blockage, the chemicals can eat their way through channels in a short plug enough to loosen it so some of it flushes out.  In that case, you'll have some drainage, but still not clean pipes, so it just buys you some time until it plugs again.

If it is a thick plug, the chemicals may not open any drainage in a reasonable time.  In that case, you now have a second problem of caustic material in the pipe you need to work on by other means.

In terms of prevention, the worst kinds of waste that cause blockages are anything sticky (starches, which turn into a kind of glue), stringy (vegetables), fats (they coagulate when cool), and coffee grounds (they pack like sand and swell).  Once there's any organic material stuck to the pipes, you also get things like molds, with mycelium that bind it together.  It's best to keep as much food waste as possible out of the plumbing.

Whenever you run the garbage disposal, including before running the dishwasher, start with cold tap water at full force, then start the disposal and squirt in some detergent while it's running, shut off the disposal, and let the water continue to run for a minute.  That will help to flush any waste through the pipes.

Comment: Excellent response thank you so much for the detailed help especially the sink technique for locating the clog location. If I find a bathroom sink that is close to the clog could I free the blockage by using the auger on that sink? Since I only have a 25ft one, I was thinking the reason I didn't clear the blockage is because it's too short.

Comment: @finoshy, can't hurt to try, but bathroom sinks with a linkage for the stopper are hard to get an auger through, and then you have a number of bends before you get to the drain pipe. If you can disassemble the trap under the sink and go in past it, you'll have a better chance.